Imposing boundary conditions on coupled ODE solutions symbolically to solve for constants
I'm trying to solve symbolically these two ODEs:
$$ \begin{array}{ll}
\eta_1 \frac{1}{r} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} r}\left(r \frac{\mathrm{d} u_1}{\mathrm{d} r}\right)  = P_1, & r \in[0, \alpha] \\
\eta_2 \frac{1}{r} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} r}\left(r \frac{\mathrm{d} u_2}{\mathrm{d} r}\right) = P_2, & r \in[\alpha, R]
\end{array} $$
With boundary conditions:
$$ \begin{aligned}
u_2(R) & = 0 \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} u_1}{\mathrm{d} r}(0) & = 0 \\
u_2(\alpha) - u_1(\alpha) & = 0 \\
\eta_1 \frac{\mathrm{d} u_1}{\mathrm{d} r}(\alpha) - \eta_2 \frac{\mathrm{d} u_2}{\mathrm{d} r}(\alpha) & = 0
\end{aligned} $$
I want to use Mathematica to solve for the constants (preferably step by step to check my math) and I wonder what would be the best way to approach this problem.
My attempt:
(* Define equations *)
eq1 = \[Eta]1 * (1/r) * D[r * D[u1[r], r], r] == P1
eq2 = \[Eta]2 * (1/r) * D[r * D[u2[r], r], r] == P2

(* Solve symbolically *)
sol1 = DSolve[eq1, u1[r], r, GeneratedParameters -> (C1[#] &)]
sol2 = DSolve[eq2, u2[r], r, GeneratedParameters -> (C2[#] &)]

(* Boundary conditions *)
bc1 = u2[R] == 0
bc2 = (D[u1[r], r] /. r -> 0) == 0
bc3 = u2[\[Alpha]] == u1[\[Alpha]]
bc4 = \[Eta]1 * (D[u1[r], r] /. r -> \[Alpha]) == \[Eta]2 * (D[u2[r], r] /. r -> \[Alpha])

But I'm not sure how to proceed to solve for the constants using the boundary conditions (especially boundary condition 2 cancels one constant to keep continuity, should I just place it as zero by hand?).
Any suggestions regarding the right workflow for this will be helpful!

Givens your second BC  du/dr at r=0 then you have to set C[1]=0 manually to eliminate the log term from the solution. You can't have such BC, since the solution has ln(r) in it. This is what we do when solving by hand.

Thank you, so I guess I can do sol1 = sol1 /. C1[1] -> 0, but how can I proceed from there effectively?

Since your solution (u1) have log(r) in the solution, then the BC du1/dr at r=0 implies that C1[1] has to be zero for the solution u1 to be finite.
eq1 = e1*(1/r)*D[r*D[u1[r], r], r] == P1
eq2 = e2*(1/r)*D[r*D[u2[r], r], r] == P2
u1Sol = DSolveValue[eq1, u1[r], r, GeneratedParameters -> (C1[#] &)]
u2Sol = DSolveValue[eq2, u2[r], r, GeneratedParameters -> (C2[#] &)]


Otherwise your BC can't be satisfied. So we are left with only Three constant of integrations
u1Sol = (DSolveValue[eq1, u1[r], r, GeneratedParameters -> (C1[#] &)]) /. C1[1] -> 0
u2Sol = DSolveValue[eq2, u2[r], r, GeneratedParameters -> (C2[#] &)]


Now set up the equations to solve for C1[2],C2[2]
 eq1=(u2Sol/.r->R)==0  (*first BC*)
 eq3 = (u2Sol /. r -> a) - (u1Sol /. r -> a) == 0
 eq4 = e1*(D[u1Sol, r] /. r -> a) - e2*(D[u2Sol, r] /. r -> a) == 0
 Solve[{eq1,eq3,eq4},{C1[2],C2[1],C2[2]}]


ps. used e1,e2 for your eta's and a for your alpha.

Thank you! However in the second equation 0 is not in the domain, so I can't cancel the constant there (C2[1] has to stay and solved for using the other boundary conditions)

@ValientProcess I just noticed that. Will fix now. I thought the BC was on both odes
